# iOS, Android, WP - Check application signature

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone

I would like to have a third party applications to communicate with my application but I need to know inside my application that I'm communicating with ones that I trust. So I should be checking their signature.

My question is: **Are there ways to check for the application signature accross all three main platforms?** (Android, iOS, Windows Phone 8.1+)

During my google research I've found something like this for Android:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); 
PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.example.app", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);`
```

I am not even completely sure if this will work in Android and I have a problem to find anything similar for iOS and WP.

Or should I use some completely different approach?

I'd appreciate any kind of help with this issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this on either iOS or WP.  Both are extremely locked down application environments and therefore do not let the children outside let alone play with each other.

I would suggest having a web page with an SDK that third-party apps can use.  They can do what they need to do without worries that the "man" will try and stop them.  Your app can then use a private SDK to retrieve any messages left for it.  Might even be a way to have the website phone home if you'll pardon the pun.